# Android Activity on top of mapfragment

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create an activity that is on top of Google Maps.
The activity should act as a tab, on the left you have the clickable items, and on the right it will load the corresponding activity.

So maybe what i want to do is create an activity that holds a tab, and each tab is an activity.

See [an example image](http://i49.tinypic.com/2wf1hxg.jpg).

My code does currently nothing more than loading the google map.

```
public class WorldApp extends Activity 
{

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alfaworldtab);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(52.022078,4.49340));
       map.moveCamera(center);

    }

}

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: It's helpful when asking a question to include the code you've written and specifically point out on the lines where you've gotten stuck trying to accomplish your goal.  It provides better context for people to assist you in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're trying to do is have multiple fragments that can interact with the map. When you work with fragments you don't really start activity's, only one activity is generally open. You can define a fragment either in the xml layout or through the use of the 
Fragment Manager.

Heres a guide all about [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

and [this one](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) you would have to use for the map part.

Hope this helps